# Calling C# dll from Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have got simple dll, it's get url and on output cuted url of image.

It's source http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?74eupvt40xzf

I'm trying to call it end send url to it in PowerShell

```
$url = "http://oiswww.eumetsat.org/IPPS/html/MSG/RGB/AIRMASS/"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(“D:\maps\eumetsat\cuturl.dll”)
[parser.Util]::GetUrl($url)
```

But when I run test.ps1 I got error that can't find type [cuturl.GetURL] please be sure that building with is are loaded.

What I do wrong?

And second question, how I can get cutted link back from lib? with which function?

Comment: You mention `[cuturl.GetURL]` as part of the error, but that isn't in your example code. Your example code looks correct and works just fine when I compile the code from everfall.com to target .NET 2.0. For the `$url` you show, however, `GetUrl()` does return an empty string, however.

Answer (score 0):

If I compile your code 'cuturl.cs' with the following command line, all works well. Except that the method return "",

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc /target:library .\cuturl.cs

Answer (score 0):

After saving the code locally I used this to load it in V2 of PowerShell:

```
add-type -path D:\PowerShellModuleRepository\Parser.Util.cs
```

As JPBlanc said the code returns nothing though:

```
[Parser.Util]::GetUrl("http://www.google.co.uk")
```

Matt